# How return language-code from django i18n middleware in settings.py or any django admin model

Tags: django-admin, django-i18n

I'm choosed a different way to make translations just because lazy translations sounds very artificial and external text files are so boring to create, so my bet is the simple great beautiful ternary. E.G.  **('English', 'Espñol')[Boolean]. Just need set Boolean(true or false) to desired language.** It's works great for me.

My problem: I tried this code in **setting.py** and got a kind of error without any relation of the this specific code something related to __init__.py I guess(Yeah It's a kind of newbie question too)

```
from django.utils import translation as lang
print ( lang.get_language() )

Error: raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. I don't mean to sound patronizing, but may I kindly suggest you stick to standard tools until you know enough to make an informed choice (which is obviously not the case if you can't even fix the above problem by yourself) ? FWIW, I already had to fix three project where the original author thought he could do better than using django's builtin i18n features and that was not exactly my definition of "fun", so don't inflict this to yourself... Just my 2 cents, really.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers after a couple days trying to see another angle and perspective you give me I decided to change this code focusin to the benefits of i18n. And after all changes and tutorials, all structure and command line study I don't know why It's not working. Maybe you can help me with this too: